# MySQL default value on NULL

Tags: mysql, default-value

I have the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE `Foo` (
  `id`         int NOT NULL,
  `FirstName`  varchar(255) NULL,
  `LastName`   varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'NONE',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);
```

When I run the following query it take the default value of `'NONE'`:

```
INSERT INTO Foo (`FirstName`) VALUES('FOO');
```

When I run the following query:

```
INSERT INTO Foo (`FirstName`, `LastName`) VALUES('FOO', NULL);
```

it gives an error:

> `[Err] 1048 - Column 'LastName' cannot be null`

What I want to achieve is that if a value is `NULL` then MySQL should use the *DEFAULT* value.
Does anybody know the solution?

Comment: because you define last name as `not null` thats why

Comment: you define your table saying that the field cannot be null. The default value works on empty, not on null. So, if you don't pass a value for the field it will default to 'NONE'. If you pass any Mysql will check the value (and fail 'cause you said not null)

Comment: @LelioFaieta ok .. i know that ... but tell me the solution that if value is null then , db take default value .. I don't want to remove null check

Answer (score 3):

try this

use `NULL` instead of  `NOT NULL`

```
CREATE TABLE `Foo` (
`id`  int NOT NULL ,
`FirstName`  varchar(255) NULL ,
`LastName`  varchar(255) NULL DEFAULT  'NONE' , 
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);
```

and query like this

use `DEFAULT` instead of `NULL`

```
INSERT INTO Foo ( `FirstName`, `LastName` ) VALUES('FOO', DEFAULT);
```

Answer (score 2):

When you use NULL it means that you want to set NULL as a value, which can't happen for the NOT NULL column.

You can explicitly insert the default value by using `DEFAULT`:

```
INSERT INTO Foo ( `FirstName`, `LastName` ) VALUES('FOO', DEFAULT);
```

Comment: but at run time, its not possible to check which value is null or not .. so if db receive null, it should take default value

Comment: you have to check on the application side if value is null and in case pass DEFAULT

Answer (score 1):

Try removing *NOT NULL* constraint.

```
INSERT INTO Foo ( `FirstName`) VALUES('FOO');
```

When you are not inserting any value manually to `lastname` you are literally inserting `'none'(default value)` into your table hence `NOT NULL` constraint passes.

---

```
INSERT INTO Foo ( `FirstName`, `LastName` ) VALUES('FOO', NULL);
```

Here you are inserting `NULL` manually to `lastname` hence you are literally inserting `NULL` into your table hence `NOT NULL` constraint fails.

**Solution:**

use `COALESCE()` function while inserting into table, Which will return non null parameter.

```
INSERT INTO Foo ( FirstName, LastName ) VALUES('FOO', COALESCE(@value, default));
```

Comment: I want when value is null then it should take default value, that's I want to achieve

Comment: Use COALESCE() function while inserting into table, Which will return non null parameter.

NSERT INTO Foo ( FirstName, LastName ) VALUES('FOO', COALESCE(@value, default));